Create global font in WPF style
I have a WPF app with a ResourceDictionary with a number of lines like this:
<FontFamily x:Key="{x:Static ipb:ImagePathButton.TopTextNormalFontFamilyKey}">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="{x:Static ipb:ImagePathButton.TopTextMouseOverFontFamilyKey}">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="{x:Static ipb:ImagePathButton.TopTextPressedFontFamilyKey}">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="{x:Static ipb:ImagePathButton.TopTextDisabledFontFamilyKey}">Segoe UI</FontFamily>

<FontFamily x:Key="{x:Static ipb:ImagePathButton.BottomTextNormalFontFamilyKey}">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="{x:Static ipb:ImagePathButton.BottomTextMouseOverFontFamilyKey}">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="{x:Static ipb:ImagePathButton.BottomTextPressedFontFamilyKey}">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="{x:Static ipb:ImagePathButton.BottomTextDisabledFontFamilyKey}">Segoe UI</FontFamily>

I would like to define the font at the top like this and use it in all the other places.
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />

How do I use that static resource in this line?
<FontFamily x:Key="{x:Static ipb:ImagePathButton.TopTextNormalFontFamilyKey}">  WHAT GOES HERE??  </FontFamily>


I think you're struggling because you've elevated FontFamily to a status it doesn't deserve. There is typically a one-to-one between a FontFamily and a static resource; not one for every "control part". One creates a general style (like "Caption" or SubTitle which addresses size and weight); then the "user" customizes further based on their preferences (if he doesn't like the default Segoe UI, for example) ... the developer doesn't decide on what Font a user will like (unless it's some custom font like "small" or "symbol")

@Gerry Schmitz This question applies to any resource. I'm simply asking how to define and set a font globally. Assume I had     Segoe UI
, how would "Font.Family.Default" be applied inbetween opening and closing tags?

It's either:   (in a "Style") or  (on a control). Or the Windows "Control Panel".
